# Contar en un metodo - POO en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, javafx, java-ee

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

En la clase AdminTelefono:
agregar el método contarMovi:
Recibe 3 teléfonos, retorna cuantos teléfonos de los que recibió pertenecen a la operadora "movi"

Crear la clase TestTelefono3, con un main, en el main:

1. Crear 3 teléfonos, algunos con la operadora "movi", otros con la
   operadora "claro"
2. **Invocar a contarMovil, lo que devuelve contarMovil guardar en una variable e imprimir**

Clase AdminTelefono

```
package com.cmc.directorio.entidades;

import com.cmc.directorio.entidades.Telefono;

public class AdminTelefono {

public void activarMensajeria(Telefono telf) {
    if (telf.getOperadora().equals("movi")) {
        telf.setTieneWhatsapp(true);
    } else {

    }

}

public int contarMovi( Telefono tel1, Telefono  tel2, Telefono  tel3){
int contar = 0;
if(tel1.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
    contar++;
} 

else if(tel2.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
        contar++;}

else if(tel3.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
    contar++;
}

return contar;
}


public void imprimir(){
    
}
```

}

Clase Telefono

```
package com.cmc.directorio.entidades;

public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String operadora;
private String numero;
private int codigo;
private boolean tieneWhatsapp;

// Constructor
public Telefono(int codigo, String operadora, String numero) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.operadora = operadora;
    this.numero = numero;
    this.tieneWhatsapp = false;

}

// Getter and Setters

public String getOperadora() {
    return operadora;
}

public void setOperadora(String operadora) {
    this.operadora = operadora;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public boolean isTieneWhatsapp() {
    return tieneWhatsapp;
}

public void setTieneWhatsapp(boolean tieneWhatsapp) {
    this.tieneWhatsapp = tieneWhatsapp;
}
```

}

Clase Main

```
package com.cmc.directorio.test;

import com.cmc.directorio.entidades.AdminTelefono;
import com.cmc.directorio.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestTelefono3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    


    Telefono tel1 = new Telefono(323523, "movi", "05445747");
    Telefono tel2 = new Telefono(323523, "movi", "5747");
    Telefono tel3 = new Telefono(323523, "claro", "05747");

    AdminTelefono a = new AdminTelefono();
    a.contarMovi(tel1, tel2, tel3);

    System.out.println("Los repetidos son " + a);

}

}
```

Pero el contador no me suma los 2 objetos que tengo creados en la operadora movi

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código en la función *contarMovi* hay un problema con los **if else** encadenados. Como se cumple la primera condición (en el ejemplo dado) entonces aumenta a contador en 1 y no evalúa las siguientes condiciones.

```
public int contarMovi( Telefono tel1, Telefono  tel2, Telefono  tel3){
    int contar = 0;

    // si se cumple esta condición no evalúa las siguientes
    if(tel1.getOperadora().equals("movi")){ 
        contar++;
    } 
    // no se evaluan las condiciones siguientes
    else if(tel2.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
        contar++;
    }
    else if(tel3.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
        contar++;
    }
    return contar;
}
```

En tus if-else cuando encuentra que una condición se cumple, ejecuta el bloque de código correspondiente y termina, es decir no evalúa las siguientes condiciones (if).

Para solucionar tu problema borrá los **else**. deja solo los **if** de la siguiente manera:

```
   if(tel1.getOperadora().equals("movi")){ 
        contar++;
   } 
   if(tel2.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
        contar++;
   }
   if(tel3.getOperadora().equals("movi")){
        contar++;
   }
```

*Los corchetes se pueden eliminar pero los dejo para evitar confusiones*

Más información acerca de la sentencia if-else [aqui](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Sentencia_if-else)